# Indexing the ValuesView of a sorteddict

Tags: python, sorteddictionary

Given the [documentation](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html), what is wrong with the following code:

```
import blist
d = blist.sorteddict({3: "first", 7: "second"})
print(d.keys()[1])
print(d.values()[1])
print(d.items()[1])
```

which prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(d.values()[1])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/_sorteddict.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    key = self._mapping.sortedkeys[index]
AttributeError: 'sorteddict' object has no attribute 'sortedkeys'
```

Comment: Ah!  It looks like a bug in blist.  I guess I should report it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. The code is ok.